# Ubuntu Desktop 14.10 installation went wrong and wiped the hard disk on windows 10

Tags: windows-10

how to recover the lost Data and Windows 10 after installing Ubuntu Desktop 14.10

Comment: 14.10 has gone end of life and so did support for it on askubuntu. Windows is off topic. There is no perfect method for getting back data that has been formatted. The OS you can re-install but you need to restore your personal data from a backup.

Answer (score 0):

well, I think that you might not be able to recover windows' data (documents, music, all of that). If you still want to use windows 10, download the official windows 10 iso from windows 10 techbench (I'd give you a link, but I'm not sure I should; just search for windows 10 techbench) and if you want to install it alongside the Ubuntu you have installed, use the custom installation to do it on a separate partition.